# Draw the national flag of France

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, geometry

There have been many other flag challenges posted but not one for the [national flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France) of [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Fifth_Republic). [This week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/November_2015_Paris_attacks) seems like an appropriate time.

Produce this flag in the fewest bytes possible:

[image: French flag]

- The image must be in a ratio of 3:2, with size at least 78 pixels wide and 52 pixels tall.
- Each stripe takes up one third of the width.
- The stripe colors from left to right are RGB: `(0, 85, 164)`, `(255, 255, 255)`, `(239, 65, 53)`.
- The image can be saved to a file or piped raw to STDOUT in any common image file format, or it can be displayed.
- Alternatively, output a block of text at least 78 characters wide made of non-whitespace characters that depicts the flag, using [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to color it. (Use standard blue, white, and red.)
- Built-in flag images/libraries are not allowed.

The shortest code in bytes wins.

## Leaderboard

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the leaderboard from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 64140; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 42156; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: Those RGB values don't match your image. From what I see, you've got RGB: `(0, 35, 149)`, `(255, 255, 255)`, `(237, 41, 57)`.

Comment: Storing the specified palette compactly is probably the trickiest part of this problem in most languages. Given that, it seems rather unfair to graphical solutions to permit ANSI output with a standard palette. Why not permit graphical solutions to use pure (0, 0, 255)/(255, 255, 255)/(255, 0 0) to level the playing field?

Comment: *Each stripe takes up one third of the width.*  Might be more interesting to use the Naval variant:  *by a regulation dated 17 May 1853, the navy went back to using the 30:33:37 proportions, which it now continues to use, as the flapping of the flag makes portions farther from the halyard seem smaller.*

Comment: `echo ` not quite big enough

Comment: How many lines are required with the ANSI text option?

Comment: Since most browser consoles don't support ansi escape codes for coloring but do allow styling with `%c` and matching css declarations is that permitted? As in: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64159/11182

Comment: Is a Windows batch file accepted? I mean to say a .cmd or .bat file. I'm new to this site, I don't know if that counts as a language.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Yes, Windows batch is an acceptable language here. There are plenty of answers in it around the site.

Comment: @JohnE I agree. The rules on colors give the ASCII-art solutions a massive advantage. They also don't make the challenge any more "difficult" (merely adds bytes really) for the languages that can use arbitrary colors and disqualifies several cool languages that can't do arbitrary colors.

Comment: Is the use of these emojis allowed ⚪️, as per [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64177/11259)?

Comment: @BenJackson with your suggestions my css example would perform better than the regular version of the flag :)

Comment: @Steve, for java, do import statements count against the byte total? My imports alone are 62 bytes lol.

Comment: Finally, I found this page again.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## CJam, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
00000000: 27 9b 22 5c 22 25 1f 22 66 7b 69 27 6d 32 37 2a  '."\"%."f{i'm27*
00000010: 7d 4e 5d 32 36 2a                                }N]26*
```

The above is a hexdump that can be reversed with `xxd -r`.

At the cost of two extra bytes – for a total of **24 bytes** – we can use background colors instead, making the output a bit prettier.

```
00000000: 27 9b 22 2c 2f 29 00 22 66 7b 69 27 6d 53 32 36  '.",/)."f{i'mS26
00000010: 2a 7d 57 4e 74 32 36 2a                          *}WNt26*
```

#### How it works

In both programs, we use the ANSI escape sequence `\x9bXYm` – where `X` is `3` for foreground color and `4` for background color, and `Y` specifies the color to use – to switch between the three colors of the flag.

```
'<CSI>       Push the '\x9b' character (Control Sequence Introducer).
"\"%<US>"    Push the string of the ISO 8859-1 characters with code
             points 34, 37, and 31.
f{           For each character in the string, push the CSI and that
             character; then:
  i            Cast the character to integer.
  'm27*        Push 27 m's. The first completes the control sequence,
               the remaining 26 will be printed.
}
N]           Wrap the generated array and "\n" in an array.
26*          Repeat it 26 times.
```

The other program is similar.

#### Output

[image: output]

Comment: I'm currently unsure how tall I should make the "image".

Comment: I went with 78x30 in my answer. Those dimensions in Lucida Console 9 pt (the default font for xterm) gave the closest to 3:2.

Comment: You could use a full block for 'prettyness'

Answer (score 77):

## Pure Bash (on OSX), 84

The default OSX terminal supports full colour emojis.  Not sure if this counts as text or graphical output.

```bash
printf -vs %26s
for i in {1..26}
do echo ${s// /}${s// /⚪️}${s// /}
done
```

#### Output looks like:

[image]

---

Alternatively:

## Bash with OSX utilities, 56

```bash
yes `dc -e3do26^d1-dn2/*p|tr 201 ⚪️`|sed 26q
```

The `dc` expression:

- calculates `3^26-1` and prints it in ternary `22222222222222222222222222`
- divides this by 2, then multiplies by `3^26`.  Output in ternary this is `1111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000`

`tr` then translates the 210 characters to ⚪️.
`yes` outputs this line indefinitely.
`sed 26q` halts output at 26 lines.

Comment: A terminal that supports emojis. *Wow.*

Comment: The first solution doesn't use the right RGB values nor does it use the standard ANSI colors, does it?

Comment: @Doorknob You're right of course - neither solutions do - so this answer may be overstepping the line.  [I've asked the OP for clarification](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/draw-the-national-flag-of-france/64177?noredirect=1#comment155155_64140)

Comment: It's just Unicode.

Comment: For me it doesn't even look like the france flag. It looks more kinda grey.

Comment: A slightly more compact version: printf -vs %26s;yes ${s// /}${s// /⚪️}${s// /}|head -26

Comment: @Daniel 67 bytes > 56 bytes.  Or am I measuring it wrong?

Comment: @steve I wasn't really expecting this answer to become so popular, especially given that there are [questions regarding its validity](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/draw-the-national-flag-of-france/64177#comment155156_64177).  Can you give a yay or nay as to whether you think it is valid?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you do byte counting? When I paste your answers at http://www.lettercount.com, I get much smaller byte counts (even though it counts emojis as 2 characters, which I think is correct.)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I was looking at the 84 byte one. The second one is better than mine, yes..

Comment: @geokavel I usually just start `wc`, paste in the script and hit ^D.  But you can also use [this online counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#yes%20%60dc%20-e3do26%5Ed1-dn2%2F%2ap%7Ctr%20201%20%F0%9F%94%B5%F0%9F%94%B4%E2%9A%AA%EF%B8%8F%60%7Csed%2026q).  lettercount.com is counting characters and not bytes.  The  and  are 4 bytes each and the ⚪️ is 6 bytes.

Comment: Hm, I've seen unicode characters counted as 1 byte before. It seems unfair to make them count as so many bytes.

Comment: @geokavel Its not unfair.  UTF-8 encodes the 128 ASCII characters as one byte each, but others (non-ASCII) are [encoded in anything from 2 to 6 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: Would UTF-16 help?

Comment: @ev3commander No, I don't think so - each character in the whole script would end up taking up 2 bytes, which would certainly significantly increase the score.  UTF-8 is best for this because it encodes almost all of what we need in just one byte per char, with just the funny dots taking up more.

Comment: Oh. I thought that since Funciton programs (using lots and lots of Unicode) are encoded with UTF-16 to get lower byte  counts, this would too.

Comment: @ev3commander For the record I just tried it - `iconv -t UTF-16 fr.sh | wc -c` gives 98 bytes.  I'm not familiar with funciton, but with a brief look over its esolangs page I would guess it would encode better in CP437 which gives most of those characters in a single byte

Answer (score 54):

## Desmos, <s>30</s> 12 bytes

```
3x>10
3x<-10
```

[Try it online.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2icdrhtvy5)

<sub>I'm not entirely sure if this is valid, please let me know if there are any issues.</sub>

Comment: Don't forget to mentiond setting the colours.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Default colors are red and blue in that order (I believe) so there is no need to set them.

Comment: You could just do `x<-1\nx>1` and tell the people to zoom in :P And they are not the default colours; they are randomly chosen afaik

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Then it's a random flag generator ;)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ They're not random for me - inputting two inequalities manually is consistently getting me red, then blue.

Comment: @Mego I got blue then green :P

Comment: This is strange. I'm getting red and blue as well.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I didnt get that `x<-1\nx>1`. Could you please explain it? What is `n` here?

Comment: @Kartik `\n` is a newline.

Comment: are those the right blue and red?

Comment: I don't think it is... nor does it fit the aspect ratio precisely.

Comment: The aspect ratio is fine (at least for me) but the colors are not right.

Comment: The colours were right for me as well as the ratio

Comment: @muddyfish the colors need to be exactly (0, 85, 164), (255, 255, 255), (239, 65, 53).

Comment: Here's a color-accurate way: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vjdeyyxyeb, but it sadly requires additional Desmos stuff. There's no way to use the default colors (even with good ordering) to get a correct result.

Answer (score 51):

### Python 2, 47 bytes

```python
s="[3%smF";print(s%4*26+s%7*26+s%1*26+"\n")*30
```

Contains unprintables - here's a hexdump (reversible with `xxd -r`):

```
00000000: 733d 221b 5b33 2573 3b31 6d46 223b 7072  s=".[3%s;1mF";pr
00000010: 696e 7428 7325 342a 3236 2b73 2537 2a32  int(s%4*26+s%7*2
00000020: 362b 7325 312a 3236 2b22 5c6e 2229 2a33  6+s%1*26+"\n")*3
00000030: 30                                       0
```

Uses ANSI escape codes to print colored characters to STDOUT - I chose "F" for France. No online link because ideone doesn't support ANSI escape codes in output.

Thanks to Dennis and xnor for some great tips.

Screenshot from xterm:

[image: flag]

Comment: You've got an extra space there. `in [0]` --> `in[0]`

Comment: 1. You can use actual ESC bytes instead of `\x1b`. 2. Bolding doesn't seem to be necessary. 3. I'm not sure if that applies to ANSI art as well, but the question seems to mandate a 3 : 2 ratio.

Comment: It's shorter to sub in the parameters with formatting: `print("\x1b[3%s;1mF"*78+"\n")%((4,)*26+(7,)*26+(1,)*26)*30`.

Comment: Or better: `s="\x1b[3%s;1mF";print(s%4*26+s%7*26+s%1*26+"\n")*30`.

Comment: Press F to pay respects

Comment: Are you sure that the first 's' should be in the code block? I can't see it, and it doesn't seem to work with it (but I haven't tested it it, I'm on my phone)

Comment: @Loovjo Thanks for pointing that out, it was the result of a failure to copy and paste correctly :)

Comment: The `█` character looks slightly nicer, e.g.  `print("\x1b[3%s;1m█"*78+"\n")%((4,)*26+(7,)*26+(1,)*26)*30`

Answer (score 43):

## HTML / SVG, 76 bytes <s>87 88 121 122 149</s>

*Saved 27 bytes thanks to @insertusernamehere*

*Saves 9 bytes thanks to @Joey*

*Saved 1 bytes thanks to @sanchies*

*Saves 1 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```html
<svg><path fill=#0055a4 d=m0,0h26v52H0 /><path fill=#ef4135 d=M52,0h26v52H52
```

Using lots of HTML syntax abuse, this can get pretty short.

---

Screenshot of output:

[image: France Flag Output]

---

Or try it (make sure your browser supports SVG):

```html
<svg><path fill=#0055a4 d=m0,0h26v52H0 /><path fill=#ef4135 d=M52,0h26v52H52
```

Comment: I tried to beat you with CSS and now I have golfed your SVG that it is even smaller than my CSS solution. :D This is the shortest I could get to work in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, it's **122 bytes** long: `<svg><rect width=78 height=52 fill="#ef4135"/><rect width=52 height=52 fill="#fff"/><rect width=26 height=52 fill=#0055a4>`

Comment: @insertusernamehere Thanks, That saved 27 bytes! I've managed to further golf this down to an astonishing 88 bytes

Comment: I think the second to last rule only applies to text output, because console output can only be basic colors.

Comment: @geokavel oh gotcha, I'll rollback

Comment: It may just be me but your flag is upside down :S

Comment: @Spaceman whoops, fixed

Comment: For me, `fill=#0055a4 />` works too (no `"`), saving a whole byte.

Comment: PHP to produce this svg (69 bytes): `<svg<?=$x='><rect width=26 height=52 fill='?>"#0055a4"/<?=$x?>#ef4135` (may be golfed even further)

Comment: It was upside down, now it's upside down and backwards!

Comment: @sanchises a whole byte? o_O _wow_ :D

Comment: @developerbmw Actually, it would be more impressive to save half a byte when you think about it.

Comment: @sanchises true, true. We need a programming language that only uses characters with values 0xF and below and the source can be compressed to use half-bytes :)

Comment: [This fails when the context it's shown in has a non-white background.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0uBQo.png) I don't think the SVG spec mandates renderers to assume a white background.

Comment: @Anko HTML defaults to a white background. This isn't really an SVG file, more of just SVG in HTML, otherwise the syntax would be invalid. A language is defined by it's implementation so I'd say it's fine

Comment: If we stick with not showing the white part, then I got it down to 79, rendering correctly in IE, Chrome, and FF: `<svg><path fill=#0055a4 d=m0,0h26v52H0 /><path fill=#ef4135 d=M52,0h26v52H52/>`. No one in their right mind should use `rect` when golfing SVG.

Comment: For me with Firefox I was able to remove the second `/` character for another byte saved.

Answer (score 29):

## [Brainfuck$](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck$), 153 bytes

```
+++++++++++++[->>>++>+++++++>++++>>>>++++++++>+++<<<<<<<<<<]>>>+>>#->$#>$#+++++++>$--->+++++[<]<<+++++[->+++++>++++++<<]>+#>($#([-]>[.>]<[<])>>>>+++<<<<)
```

Outputs the image with ANSI color codes. I chose a height of 30 [like Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64141/30164).

The reference implementation from 2009 linked on the esolangs page has gone missing. You can run it using this interpreter made by me, which supports everything from the esolangs page.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function(){document.querySelector("#r").addEventListener("click",function(){var  c=document.querySelector("#c").value,u=document.querySelector("#i").value,d=Array(30000).fill(0),p=0,i=0,q=0,s=[],o=document.querySelector("#o");o.value="";eval(c.replace(/[^]/g,function(e,i){return{"+":"d[p]=(-~d[p]+256)%256;","-":"d[p]=(~-d[p]+256)%256;",">":"p++;","<":"p--;",",":"d[p]=q-u.length?u[q++].charCodeAt()%256:0;",".":"o.value+=String.fromCharCode(d[p]);","[":"while(d[p]){","]":"}","#":"s.push(d[p]);","$":"d[p]=s.pop();",";":"d[p]=(parseInt(prompt())%256+256)%256;",":":"o.value+=d[p].toString();","(":"for(var i"+i+"=d[p];i"+i+">0;i"+i+"--){",")":"}","@":"o.value+=('D '+d.slice(0,20)+'\\nS '+s+'\\nIP '+i+' DP '+p);"}[e]||"";}));});});
```

```html
<label for=c>Code:</label><br/><textarea style="width:100%;height:15em;white-space:pre" id=c>+++++++++++++[-&gt;&gt;&gt;++&gt;+++++++&gt;++++&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;++++++++&gt;+++&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;]&gt;&gt;&gt;+&gt;&gt;#-&gt;$#&gt;$#+++++++&gt;$---&gt;+++++[&lt;]&lt;&lt; init sequence to cells 3 to 10&#10;+++++[-&gt;+++++&gt;++++++&lt;&lt;] set cells 1~2 to 25 &amp; 30&#10;&gt;+ set cell 1 to 26&#10;# push 26 to stack&#10;&gt; go to cell 2&#10;( do 30 times&#10;    $# get 26 to this cell from stack&#10;    ( do 26 times&#10;        [-]&gt;[.&gt;]&lt;[&lt;] print sequence&#10;    )&#10;    &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;+++&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; change color to white&#10;    $# get 26 to this cell from stack&#10;    ( do 26 times&#10;        [-]&gt;[.&gt;]&lt;[&lt;] print sequence&#10;    )&#10;    &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;------&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; change color to red&#10;    $# get 26 to this cell from stack&#10;    ( do 26 times&#10;        [-]&gt;[.&gt;]&lt;[&lt;] print sequence&#10;    )&#10;    &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;+++&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt; change color to blue&#10;    ++++++++++. print newline&#10;)</textarea><br/><button id=r>Run</button><br/><label for=i>Input:</label><br/><textarea id=i style="width:100%"></textarea><br/><label for=o>Output:</label><br/><textarea readonly id=o style="width:100%;height:15em;white-space:pre"></textarea>
```

## Brainfuck, 258 bytes

This is basically the same thing, but just in plain old Brainfuck.

```
>>+++++++++++++[-<<++>>>>++>+++++++>++++>++++>+++++>++++>++++++++>+++[<]<]>>+>>->>------>--->+++++[<]<<<++++[>+++++[->+++++<]>+[>>[.>]<[<]<-]>>>>>+++[<]+++++[-<+++++>]<+[>>[.>]<[<]<-]>>>>>------[<]+++++[-<+++++>]<+[>>[.>]<[<]<-]>>>>>+++[<]<++++++++++.[-]<<-]
```

Or, if you prefer this one in **oOo CODE** (984 bytes):

```
one day ThERe WIlL Be PEaCE iN ThIS wORlD
OnE DaY ThERe WiLl Be peaCe iN ThIS wOrld
one day theRe WIlL be pEaCE iN ThIS wORlD
OnE DaY theRe WIlL Be PEaCe in ThIS wORlD
OnE day ThERe WIlL Be PEaCe in ThIS wORlD
OnE day ThERe WIlL Be PEaCE iN ThIS wOrld
OnE DaY ThErE wilL bE PeaCe IN this woRlD
one day There will Be pEacE in ThiS woRld
one Day TheRe will Be PEaCE iN ThIS wOrLd
onE dAY thEre WilL Be PEaCE iN ThIs World
OnE DaY ThERe WIlL bE pEace in ThIS wORlD
OnE DaY thErE Will Be PeAce in this WoRLd
one dAY thErE wilL bE PeaCE in tHIs world
one day theRe WIlL Be PeAce iN tHIS wORlD
OnE DaY ThErE wIll be PEaCE iN ThIS wORlD
one dAY thERe WiLl be peace In THis worLD
onE dAy thErE WilL Be peACe in this world
one Day TheRe wIll Be pEace In thIs WORlD
OnE DaY ThERe WiLl Be peaCE iN ThIS wORlD
OnE day tHEre WIlL bE peace in tHiS World
oNE daY tHere WiLL be PEace IN this world
one day ThERe WIlL bE peaCe IN thIS wORlD
OnE DaY ThERe WIlL Be PEaCE iN THis WoRld
oNE daY thERe wiLL
```

Answer (score 25):

## LaTeX, 139 bytes

Thanks to @WChargin for saving 21 bytes.

```
\documentclass{proc}\input color\begin{document}\def\z#1!{{\color[rgb]{#1}\rule{4cm}{8cm}}}\z0,.33,.64!\z1,‌​1,1!\z.94,.25,.21!\end{document}
```

This prints the following 12cm*8cm image on an A4 page:

[image]

*Note that "Page 1" is also printed at the bottom of the page*

Comment: Well this is about 100 bytes shorter than my `asymptote` solution...

Comment: `s.\newcommand\z[1].\def\z#1` to save a bunch of bytes. Also, you can shave off a few by using `\def\z#1!{…}\z0,.33,.64!\z1,1,1!\z.94,.25,.21!`—that is, use your own delimiters instead of braces for grouping

Comment: You can also `\input color`

Comment: For completeness, revised version (139 bytes): `\documentclass{proc}\input color\begin{document}\def\z#1!{{\color[rgb]{#1}\rule{4cm}{8cm}}}\z0,.33,.64!\z1,1,1!\z.94,.25,.21!\end{document}`

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by using the active character `~` in place of `\z`.

Comment: If you bypass LaTeX’s output routine and just ship a box containing the flag, you don’t need any of the usual nonsense like `\documentclass` and `\begin/\end{document}`. (This also neatly gets rid of the unwanted “Page 1”.) On an unrelated note, the outer brackets inside the definition of the macro are unnecessary. So all in all, here is a 116 byte version: ``\input color\catcode`@11\def~#1!{\color[rgb]{#1}\rule{4cm}{8cm}}\shipout\hbox{~0,.33,.64!~1,1,1!~.94,.25,.21!}\@@end``. (Here, `\@@end` is LaTeX’s renaming of the primitive TeX command `\end`. The `\catcode` change is to make it work.)

Comment: Oh, and a 108 byte version using dirty tricks: `\input color\def~#1!{\color[rgb]{#1}\rule{4cm}{8cm}}\shipout\hbox{~0,.33,.64!~1,1,1!~.94,.25,.21!}\batchmode`. Here, the `\end` command is omitted entirely; this leads to an error, but the `\batchmode` silences it and allows the job to finish. In fact, if you are running LaTeX in an IDE rather than from a terminal, chances are it may have already set `\batchmode` from the command line, in which case it may be omitted, too.

Answer (score 24):

### Bash + ImageMagick, <s>60</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```
convert -sample 78x52\! - a<<<"P3 3 1 255 0 85 164 255 255 255 239 65 53"
```

(ugh, +17 chars due to color requirements I didn't notice earlier...)

Outputs to the file `a`, in netpbm format:

```
llama@llama:~$ convert -sample 78x52\! - a<<<"P3 3 1 255 0 85 164 255 255 255 239 65 53"
llama@llama:~$ file a
a: Netpbm image data, size = 78 x 52, rawbits, pixmap
```

Can also output in PNG, if you change the filename to `a.png` (+4 chars).

Output:

[image]

Comment: `convert -sample 78x52\! - a<<<"P3 3 1 255 0 85 164 255 255 255 239 65 53"`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks! That saves 4 chars and doesn't exit with an error. (Also, I never knew ImageMagick could read from / write to STDIN.)

Comment: You can use `-scale` instead of `-sample`; also, the backslash doesn't seem to be necessary

Answer (score 24):

## Pyth, 27 bytes

```
 .w*52[smmdGc3CM"\0U¤ÿÿÿïA5
```

There are some unprintable chars, so here's a hexdump:

```
00000000   2E 77 2A 35  32 5B 73 6D  6D 64 47 63  33 43 4D 22  .w*52[smmdGc3CM"
00000010   5C 30 55 A4  FF FF FF EF  41 35                     \0U.....A5
```

This creates a file `o.png`, which is exactly 78 pixels wide and 52 pixels tall:

[image]

#### Explanation:

```
.w*52[smmdGc3CM"........
               "........  a string containing the bytes 
                          0, 85, 164, 255, 255, 255, 239, 65, 53
             CM           convert them to integers
           c3             split into 3 lists
      smmdG               duplicate each list 26 times
     [                    put them into a list
  *52                     and duplicate it 52 times
.w                        save it as an image o.png
```

Comment: For a second, I thought I had grossly misunderstood the PNG specification.

Comment: `save it as an image o.png`, but there's no ".png" anywhere?

Comment: @AsidShout How do you call the program? If you use `python3 pyth.py code.pyth`, then you can find it in the same directory.

Answer (score 22):

## HTML (quirks mode), 68 bytes

This uses quirks mode to render the flag.

The HTML is **VERY** invalid, but works on a stock Android 4.4.2 browser and on Firefox 42.0 (on Windows 7 x64).

```html
<table width=78 height=52><td bgcolor=0055a4><td><td bgcolor=ef4135>
```

The flag is rendered with the right size and the standard red and blue colors. All webpages start with a standard white background.

---

---

As an alternative:

A **perfectly valid** HTML5 version (141 bytes):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><title>x</title><table style=width:78px;height:52px><tr><td style=background:#0055a4><td><td style=background:#ef4135></table>
```

Check it's validity on: https://html5.validator.nu/

Print-screen of the result:

[image: validation result]

Comment: Are you sure? When I have a HTML file with only this line, it doesn't work in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. If the file contains other HTML-elements after that line, it works for me. So maybe you can't discard the trailing `>`?

Comment: "Perfectly valid"? It should be `style="..."` if that's what you're going for in the second example.

Comment: @mbomb007 What I am going for is to create the smallest valid HTML code. It validates with the official validator, so, it is **perfectly valid** HTML. You can try it yourself if you don't believe.

Comment: @mbomb007 Also, missing quotes is the smallest issue: there's no `<html>`, no `<head>`, no `<body>`, no `</tr>`, no `</td>` and no closing of all missing tags.

Comment: @insertusernamehere You were right. It was bugging on Android too. I tested it on jsfiddle. But when accessing `data:text/html,<table width=78 height=52><td bgcolor=0055a4><td><td bgcolor=ef4135>`, it wasn't working. Fixed it now, and use the link to test it.

Answer (score 20):

### ffmpeg, <s>110</s> <s>113</s> <s>116</s> <s>117</s> <s>119</s> <s>108</s> 100 bytes

Display, using ffplay, 100 bytes:

```
ffplay -f lavfi color=#0055a4:49x98[r];color=white:49x98[w];color=#ef4135:49x98[b];[r][w][b]hstack=3
```

Saved to file, using ffmpeg, 108 bytes:

```
ffmpeg -lavfi color=#0055a4:49x98[r];color=white:49x98[w];color=#ef4135:49x98[b];[r][w][b]hstack=3 -t 1 .png
```

The current version of the command will abort with an error BUT will output a single image ".png", same as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Abusing ffmpeg to make images...

Comment: Heh, I saw this question and thought of doing the same. Nice job making it compact. If it is allowed you can make it slightly smaller by using `white` instead of `#ffffff`: the values should be the same.

Comment: I know. Wasn't bothered enough. Will do it now.

Comment: Does #fff work?

Comment: No. But I can skip the f in f.png

Comment: Where exactly is the output? I don't see a flag anywhere, but I do get `-bash: [r][w][b]hstack=3: command not found`.

Comment: A file `.png` is created i.e. Name is blank and extension is PNG. Works here on Win7.

Answer (score 17):

## CSS, 127 <s>128</s> <s>144</s> bytes

```css
body:before,body:after{content:'';float:left;width:33%;height:100%;background:#0055a4}body:after{float:right;background:#ef4135}
```

No need for another tag, works solely with the `body`-element.

**Edits**

- *Saved* **16 bytes** by removing `display:block;` and some `;`.
- *Saved* **1 byte**, removed the trailing `}`.

Comment: Though technically CSS isn't a programming language by our definitions.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I know – just wanted to beat [SVG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64148/41859).

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ is right, this is not a valid answer.

Comment: This is no longer beating the SVG answer.

Comment: @Riking I know, after I posted this answer I outplayed myself by golfing the SVG answer to a lower byte count. :)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ What exactly are the definitions?

Comment: @Random832 [These, mon amis, are the definitions.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Well, if that includes HTML+CSS, this is just the combination of the given CSS file with the empty HTML document.

Comment: @Random832 HTML isn't a programming language alone by our standards.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Then you're going to have to make it a bit more clear what you meant by this link, because it links to a question, and the highest voted answer is Peter Taylor's, and he says in a comment on another answer that HTML+CSS qualifies.

Comment: @Random832 Don't be ticked. If you think it's okay, then roll with it. Only my opinion.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ it the css was saved as a SASS file, since SASS is a scripting language would it be a valid answer?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan So long as the program is valid, yeah.

Comment: Yeah, regular CSS is a valid SASS file.

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript, 140 <s>143</s> <s>147</s> <s>151</s> <s>153</s> bytes

```js
   with(document)with(body.appendChild(createElement`canvas`).getContext`2d`)for(i=2;i--;fillRect(i*52,0,26,52))fillStyle=i?"#ef4135":"#0055a4"
```

---

**Edits**

- *Saved* **2 bytes** by replacing `2*i*26` with `i*52`. Thanks to [Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c%E1%B4%8F%C9%B4%E1%B4%8F%CA%80-ob%CA%80%C9%AA%E1%B4%87%C9%B4).
- *Saved* **4 bytes** by refactoring the `for`-loop. Thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions).
- *Saved* **2 bytes** by using the `with`-statement. Thanks to [Dendrobium](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20519/dendrobium).
- *Saved* **2 bytes** by turning increment into decrement. Thanks to [Shaun H](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43545/shaun-h).
- *Saved* **3 bytes** by replacing `fillStyle=["#0055a4","#ef4135"][i]` with `i?"#ef4135":"#0055a4"`.

Comment: `2*i*26` can become `52*i`, no?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Of course it can. Thanks. It's way beyond my bed time.

Comment: By simply rearranging the for loop, you can cut 4 bytes: ``for(i=0;i<2;x.fillRect(i++*52,0,26,52))x.fillStyle=["#0055a4","#ef4135"][i]``

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks a lot, I've updated the answer.

Comment: You can shave off 2 bytes by using the `with` statement: `with(document)with(body.appendChild(createElement\`canvas\`).getContext\`2d\`)for(i=0;i<2;fillRect(i++*52,0,26,52))fillStyle=["#0055a4","#ef4135"][i]`

Comment: save a byte:

`x=(d=document).body.appendChild(d.createElement`canvas`).getContext`2d`;for(i=3;--i;x.fillRect(i*52,0,26,52))x.fillStyle=[,"#ef4135","#0055a4"][i]`

Comment: @Dendrobium That's good. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShaunH I had to write it a bit different, but it saved another 2 bytes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

## TI-Basic, <s>52</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
GridOff
AxesOff
11
Shade(-Ans,Ans,Xmin,Xmin/3
Shade(-Ans,Ans,Xmax/3,Xmax,1,1,Ans
```

(assumes a default [-10,10,1] by [-10,10,1] graph area)

Would be 4 bytes shorter without the first 2 lines, but by default would have axes and would not look as nice.

Looks like this:

[image]

If the shading is invalid for the challenge, let me know!

Without the first 2 lines, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I would also include the version without the first three lines just as a comparison.

Comment: I think you can just go from Ymin to Ymax. You can also assume a default screen from -10 to 10. I'm also not sure about the validity of this, since the red and blue regions are only half shaded.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I edited my post to show why I didn't use just Ymin and Ymax. I didn't realize I could assume a default screen, but you aren't clear about what that default screen is. Could you please clarify? About the "half-shaded" thing, that is just how TI-Basic shades things, if it is invalid, I will promptly change it.

Comment: A default screen is Ymin=Xmin=-10, Ymax=Xmax=10. The calculator starts with those window settings, and AxesOn etc, so you can assume them.

Comment: This doesn't use the right RGB values, does it?

Comment: @Doorknob As far as I know, it's impossible to do that without resorting to witchcraft.

Comment: @Doorknob I can verify that. The color tokens represent fixed colors; to change those nothing short of assembly will work.

Comment: `RED` isn't any shorter than `11`. Both are 2 bytes. You can also golf by 2 bytes by using `11:Shade(-Ans,Ans,Xmin,Xmin/3:Shade(-Ans,Ans,Xmax/3,Xmax,1,1,Ans`.

Comment: @ThomasKwa `RED` is more pretentious though. ;) Thanks for the tips though!

Answer (score 12):

### R, 59 bytes

```
frame();rect(0:2/3,0,1:3/3,1,,,c("#0055a4",0,"#ef4135"),NA)
```

Output is displayed:

[image]

One can also do 49 bytes with

```
barplot(rep(1,3),,0,col=c("#0055a4",0,"#ef4135"))
```

if you do not mind the axes and borders:

[image]

Comment: The ratio seems wrong. I think you have a 2:3 to ratio on a single-colored rectangle instead of a 3:2ratio on the whole flag.

Comment: The ratio can be adjusted manually by resizing the plotting window.

Comment: To qualify, your entry should work 'out of the box'. Else, anyone can post a 6-pixel solution and say 'You can manually zoom in'.

Comment: You say 'axes', I say 'flag pole'.

Comment: @sanchises: I'm French and I say f**k it. LIBERTE!

Comment: @flodel I give you, f**k it, égalité! :)

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, <s>63</s> <s>94</s> 103 bytes

When I first saw this challenge, I thought *Sweet! Mathematica would be perfect for this!* until I noticed that built-ins were banned :'(

But wait! I can use bar graphs!

```
r=RGBColor;BarChart[{1,1,1},ChartStyle->{r@"#0055a4",White,r@"#ef4135"},BarSpacing->0,AspectRatio->2/3]
```

(Thanks to Martin Büttner for shaving off 5 bytes but adding 16)

Looks like this:

[image]

If you add `,Axes->None` it looks like this:

[image]

If you don't care about the border, you can use this: (95 bytes)

```
r=RGBColor;BarChart[{1,1},ChartStyle->{r@"#0055a4",r@"#ef4135"},BarSpacing->1,AspectRatio->2/3,Axes->None]
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Without axes:

[image]

Comment: `Axes->None`. You should also specifty `AspectRatio->2/3`. Renaming `RGBColor` is simple: `r=RGBColor;...r["..."]`. You can also use prefix-notation to save two more bytes `r@"#0055a4"`.

Comment: If you don't need the outline, try `BarChart[{1, 1}, ChartStyle -> {RGBColor["#0055a4"], Red}, BarSpacing -> 1]`.  The Red looks close enough.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Meh, since the question specifies a particular RGB value, that one should be used exactly.

Comment: My main recommendation was to draw two rectangles, not three.  You are technically correct about Red, however.

Comment: Wouldn't the borders around the bars invalidate this solution?

Comment: Why not the more direct 65 bytes `Image@{{{0,85,164},{6,6,6}!,{239,65,53}}/255}~ImageResize~{78,52}`?

Answer (score 11):

### [Blitz 2D/3D](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Products/blitz3d.php), <s>154</s> 108 bytes

This produces exactly the same thing as the example given in the question (except for the anti-aliasing at the edges where colors meet).

```
Graphics 800,533
ClsColor 255,255,255
Cls
Color 0,35,149
Rect 0,0,267,533
Color 237,41,57
Rect 533,0,267,533
```

Output is displayed and it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript (ES6) 117 bytes

Draws it in the console

```js
for(i=c=s=[];i<156;c[i++]=`color:${[,'blue','#fff'][i%3]||(s+=`
`,'red')}`)s+='%c'+'+'.repeat(26);console.log(s,...c)
```

Comment: For `'white'` I think it's shorter to do: `#fff`. Also, the Red and Blue colors must match the colors specified in the spec

Comment: You can save a few bytes with `i=c=s=[]` instead of `i=0,c=[],s=''` after updating the colours that might help a little...

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ When outputting in text, you can use the standard colors (`red` and `blue`). It's the 2nd point, counting from the bottom. This is within the spec.

Comment: @DomHastings Nice tip, clever use of coercion. Thanks!

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ Thanks for the tip, I think the colours are valid because like Ismael said I am using text output. The browser consoles I've tried don't support actual ANSI codes but I've asked for clarification on that.

Comment: On Chrome, this comes out at least 2 to 3 times taller than it should be for the 2:3 ratio (I think, at least)

Comment: @sysreq Its text in the console... I have no control over your console's lineheight. It's 78 characters wide 52 tall.

Comment: This doesn't use the right RGB values nor does it use the standard ANSI colors, does it?

Comment: @Doorknob I was under the impression that ANSI has a standardisation of the color names and not the RGB values. That is platform/application independent.

Comment: @Doorknob It uses the color red (#F00), white (#FFF) and blue (#00F). If you check the link provided by the O.P., you will notice that those colors are in the "light" line. So, yes, those are valid.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The question specifies the RGB values that must be used.

Comment: @Doorknob I suggest that you read the 2nd point counting from the bottom. It talks about textual output. The colors are fine. Read it and move along. Nothing invalid here.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel This answer does not fall under the category "*Alternatively, output a block of text at least 78 characters wide made of non-whitespace characters that depicts the flag, using ANSI color codes to color it. (Use standard blue, white, and red.)*" It a.) doesn't use ANSI color codes and b.) doesn't use standard blue, white, and red. Therefore, it has to use the RGB values specified.

Comment: @Doorknob It outputs text to a console, using the defined colors. If you wish, ping me on the chat. This discussion is getting pointless pretty quicly. I gave my upvote and I will keep it.

Answer (score 11):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/pb), 68 bytes

```
cw[Y!52]{cccw[X!26]{b[77]>}ccccw[X!52]{b[77]>}cw[X!78]{b[77]>}<[X]v}
```

Wow, a challenge that pb is actually kinda good for! Those are few and far between.

When I was writing the spec for pb, I included coloured output mostly as a joke. The language was named after a "paintbrush", why would it *not* do colour? Other than example programs, this is the second time I've ever used it. It is implemented with ANSI codes as the question requires.

I used 'M' as the character to output with because it's fairly dense.

**Output:**

[image]

I resized that screenshot vertically to be two thirds of its height because letters aren't square. The output is 78 by 52, but the original screenshot looks really wrong.

**With comments and indentation and junk:**

```
c               # Increase output colour by 1
                # 0 (White) -> 1 (Red)
                # Loop ends with output colour == 1, this is cheaper than
                # setting it back to white every time.

w[Y!52]{        # While the brush's Y coordinate is not 52:
    ccc           # Increase output colour by 3
                    # 1 (Red) -> 4 (Blue)

    w[X!26]{      # While the brush's X coordinate is not 26:
        b[77]       # Write 'M' at the brush's coordinates
        >           # Increase X coordinate by 1
    }             

    cccc          # Increase output colour by 4
                    # 4 (Blue) -> 8 mod 8 = 0 (White)

    w[X!52]{      # While the brush's X coordinate is not 52:
        b[77]       # (same as before)
        >         
    }             

    c             # Increase output colour by 1
                    # 0 (White) -> 1 (Red)

    w[X!78]{      # While the brush's X coordinate is not 78:
        b[77]       # (same as before)
        >
    }

    <[X]          # Set X back to 0
    v             # Increase Y by 1
}
```

Comment: 78x30 will get you the dimensions you want for terminal output.

Comment: @Mego Yeah, but I'm not sure if it's allowed.

Comment: The resulting output on xterm in the default font matches the specified dimensions.

Comment: I'd feel weird measuring the size of console output in anything but "characters", though.

Comment: When your characters are 1.2x as tall as they are wide, they don't make for very good pixels.

Answer (score 10):

## MATLAB, <strike>82</strike> <strike>79</strike> 78 bytes

```
x=[0 1 1 0];y(3:4)=2;fill(x,y,[0 85 164]/255,x+1,y,'w',x+2,y,[239 65 53]/255)
```

Output looks like:
[image]

Comment: Which version of MATLAB? Doesn't work on r2013a as colours need to be decimal numbers in the range [0,1].

Comment: The following line works ```fill(x,y,[0 85 164]/255,x+1,y,'w',x+2,y,[239 65 53]/255)``` and saves you 2 bytes. :) I'd also use semi-colons instead of newlines to avoid extra stuff being printed out.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I spaced on the 0-1 color scale, it's been a little while since I've had to specify colors. As for the semicolons/newlines, I was choosing readability over console writing, but I've changed my answer

Comment: Surely [54](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@ck1@cqpCYk2OtkJyTmlgEopKt/1fYRhsoGAKhQSxXpYaxlYmmrRFXWmZOjkaFTqWOepK6ToW2IYhVDmIZgVhF6pr/EysyixXy09Ks/wMA)...? If you don't want to use default colours you can still save a few bytes ([67](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@ck1@cqpCYk2OtkJyTmlgEopKt/1fYRhsoGAKhQSxXpYaxlYmmrRFXWmZOjkaFTqUOUE7PWEHPLFanQtsQyFcvVweyjEAyepZgKaNYzf@JFZnFCvlpadb/AQ)), by taking some more liberty with the exact RGB values.

Comment: Also, in newer versions of Matlab you can use the default colormap for the line colours (`lines`) to get [68](https://tio.run/##HYhBCoAgAATvvsJbSh7SOiW@JDqIKAhLQkbp681iDjs7yV329s0hZU8toKmDt@c3TrditonKzrSTyuZ14UYRGMTDZxIiwIqoAkyKlYsyyn6GZ@im/qx65s2WmGkKQbcX)

Comment: Just realised one more thing, the background of a figure is already white, therefore [44](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@ck1@cqpCYk2OtkJyTmlgEopKt/1fYRhsoGAKhQSxXpYaxlYmmrRFXWmZOjkaFTqWOepK6ToW2EYhVpK75P7Eis1ghPy3N@j8A) 

Answer (score 10):

## C, 115 bytes

[image]

```
#define c"[48;2;%d;%d;%dm%9c"
d=255;main(a){while(a++<9)printf(c c c c,0,85,164,0,d,d,d,0,239,65,53,0,0,0,0,10);}
```

Contains unprintables:

```
00000000: 2364 6566 696e 6520 6322 1b5b 3438 3b32  #define c".[48;2
00000010: 3b25 643b 2564 3b25 646d 2539 6322 0a64  ;%d;%d;%dm%9c".d
00000020: 3d32 3535 3b6d 6169 6e28 6129 7b77 6869  =255;main(a){whi
00000030: 6c65 2861 2b2b 3c39 2970 7269 6e74 6628  le(a++<9)printf(
00000040: 6320 6320 6320 632c 302c 3835 2c31 3634  c c c c,0,85,164
00000050: 2c30 2c64 2c64 2c64 2c30 2c32 3339 2c36  ,0,d,d,d,0,239,6
00000060: 352c 3533 2c30 2c30 2c30 2c30 2c31 3029  5,53,0,0,0,0,10)
00000070: 3b7d 0a                                  ;}.
```

For this program to work, a couple of things need to be true:

- The terminal supports the `ESC [48;2;<r>;<g>;<b>m` "truecolor" escape sequence.
- The terminal is not xterm, becase xterm's implementation of the above will produce slightly wrong colors.
- The terminal completely ignores NUL characters.

It also looks nicer if your terminal's background is black.

To change to height of the flag, pass command line arguments to  the program. For every argument passed, the flag becomes one line shorter. *It's not a bug, it's a feature!*

Output:

[image]

Comment: Had trouble compiling this with `gcc` (version 5.1.1).  Any specific flags needed to compile?    "a.c:1:10: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
 #define c"\x1b[48;2;%d;%d;%dm"

Comment: @Steve is that a warning our an error?

Comment: @Steve Just tested it again, gcc 5.2.1. No flags. Produced 12 warnings but made a working binary.

Comment: apologies - works fine - got confused by the warnings (and the fact that the code looks pretty cryptic to a C newbie like me)

Answer (score 9):

### CSS, 102 <s>110</s> <s>111</s> <s>114</s> bytes

```css
*{background:linear-gradient(90deg,#0055a4 33%,#fff 33%,#fff 66%,#ef4135 66%) 0 0/78px 52px no-repeat
```

Comment: `* *{background:linear-gradient(90deg,#0055a4,#0055a4 33%,#fff 33%,#fff 66%,#ef4135 66%) 0 0/78px 52px no-repeat}` - one byte shorter

Comment: actually a single * is enough :) Thanks!

Comment: +1; You could save another byte by removing the trailing `}`.

Comment: You can delete the first color, you save 8 bytes.

Comment: You can replace last `66%` with `0`.

Answer (score 9):

### Visual Basic+Excel, <strike>618</strike> 137 bytes

Just curious to see how this can be golfed.

**EDIT:** Curiosity sated, thanks to @Neil and @JimmyJazzx, 618 bytes dropped right down to 137 bytes

```
Sub a(): Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 26: Range("A1:A13").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 85, 164): Range("C1:C13").Interior.Color = RGB(239, 65, 53): End Sub
```

[image: Excel flag]

Comment: Recording a macro results in terribly inefficient code. Try `Range("A1:C13").Interior.ColorIndex = 5` and `Range("G1:I13").Interior.ColorIndex = 3` which seems to suffice.

Comment: Sorry, that was Excel 2003, and I forgot to include the `ActiveWorkbook.Colors` to specify the exact RGB values. Excel 2007 has additional colour options but I don't know them offhand.

Comment: I get 137 bytes with a few Quick Changes. I think you can Cut this down more but this is the easy changes.
`Sub a():Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth=26:Range("A1:A13").Interior.Color=RGB(0,85,164):Range("C1:C13").Interior.Color=RGB(239,65,53):End Sub`

Comment: I get 135 with `Sub a:Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth=26:Range("A1:A13").Interior.Color=RGB(0,85,164):Range("C1:C13").Interior.Color=RGB(239,65,53):End Sub`

Answer (score 8):

## [iKe](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/ike/ike.html), 43 bytes

```
,(0 0;"|"\"#0055A4|#FFF|#EF4135";52#,&3#26)
```

This is an example of a "raw tuple" iKe program- it's just a description of an origin (`0 0`), a palette (`3 7#"#0055A4#FFFFFF#EF4135"`) and a bitmap (`+52#'&3#26`). You need to wrap a description like this in a function or use references to views if you want to animate it.

The palette is a very simple way of creating a series of CSS colors, hex equivalents of the spec.

```
  3 7#"#0055A4#FFFFFF#EF4135"
("#0055A4"
 "#FFFFFF"
 "#EF4135")
```

If the color requirements were less stringent we could use one of iKe's built-in palettes and save a considerable number of characters:

```
windows@7 0 4
```

[image: flag]

Try it [in your browser](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/ike/ike.html?gist=ff4cdd10b8ec75ed81d7).

### Edit:

Saved one byte by using a short `#FFF` CSS color for the white stripe:

```
,(0 0;3 7#"#0055A4#FFFFFF#EF4135";+52#'&3#26)
,(0 0;"|"\"#0055A4|#FFF|#EF4135";+52#'&3#26)
```

If anyone else is interested in playing with iKe, there's a manual on the [github repo](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/tree/gh-pages/ike). [here's another problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57152/38485) I solved using iKe.

### Edit 2:

Saved one byte with a simpler way to construct the bitmap:

```
+52#'&3#26
52#,&3#26
```

My question in the OP hasn't been answered, but for the record if more flexible color requirements are permitted, this program would be 30 bytes by using the Windows 3.1 palette:

```
,(0 0;windows@7 0 4;52#,&3#26)
```

[image: flag2]

Since this problem was posted, iKe has gained a feature which automatically centers textures drawn without a position, which could save another 3 bytes, but this would be against the rules:

```
,(;windows@7 0 4;52#,&3#26)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Dyalog APL (<s>47</s> 44)

```
⎕SM←↑1 21 41{(''⍴⍨2/20)1⍺,⍵,⍨4↑0}¨2*8 11 10
```

Result:

[image: flag]

Comment: can you do `2*8 11 10`?

Comment: @ThomasKwa: thanks

Answer (score 7):

## ShaderToy (GLSL), 147 bytes

```
void mainImage(out vec4 o,vec2 i){float x=i.x/iResolution.x*3.0;vec3 w=vec3(255,255,255);o=vec4((x<1.0?vec3(0,85,164):x<2.0?w:vec3(239,65,53))/w,1);}
```

[See it here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lddGRn)

Not particularly exciting. I'm sure there are ways to golf it more; I'll take a crack when I get home.

Comment: The link redirects to https://www.shadertoy.com/error :/

Comment: A bit shorter version (122 bytes): `void mainImage(out vec4 o,vec2 i){o.rgb=vec3[](vec3(0,85,164),vec3(255),vec3(239,65,53))[int(3.*i.x/iResolution.x)]/255.;}`

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
s(98,49)=0;imshow(cat(3,[s w=s+255 w-18],[s+35 w s+41],[s+149 w s+57])/255);
```

Displays the image:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Processing, 100 Bytes

```
size(78,52);background(255);noStroke();fill(#0055A4);rect(0,0,26,52);fill(#EF4135);rect(52,0,26,52);
```

Displays this:
[image: France]

(The naive solution is shorter than my first one.)

Comment: I think Processing's drawing commands can come out ahead of pixel pushing here: `size(78,52);noStroke();int[]p={0xFF0055A4,255,0xFFEF4135};for(int c:p){translate(26,0);fill(c);rect(0,0,-26,52);}`

Comment: @JohnE Lol, yeah i just noticed that.

Comment: @JohnE Even my super basic solution is shorter than yours!

Comment: haha- looks like we both overcomplicated it

Comment: how about abusing the scale instructions? This works on sketchpad.cc but might break in Processing 3: `size(78,52);scale(26,52);fill(#EF4135);stroke(#0055A4);rect(0,-1,0,2);stroke(255);rect(1,-1,3,3);`

Comment: @JohnE It doesn't work when I paste it into Processing, because there seem to be some unprintable characters. I don't really understand what you're doing though. Why are you using `stroke()`?

Comment: By scaling up the canvas I shorten the constants necessary to draw 26x52 rectangles, but also the stroke (which is on by default) will be 26 pixels wide. Thus, instead of drawing a background I can draw two stripes by using the edge of one rectangle. The solution doesn't depend on any unprintable characters, so if there's an issue with that it's just stackoverflow screwing it up.

Comment: `background(-1)` is one byte shorter than `background(255)`

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 70 bytes

```php
0000000: 424d 0000 0000 0000 0000 2300 0000 0c00  BM........#.....
0000010: 0000 2001 c000 0100 0800 a455 00ff ffff  .. ........U....
0000020: 3541 ef3c 3f66 6f72 283b 3665 343e 2469  5A.<?for(;6e4>$i
0000030: 3b29 6563 686f 2063 6872 2824 692b 2b2f  ;)echo chr($i++/
0000040: 3936 2533 293b                           96%3);
```

*The above is a hexdump which may be reversed with `xxd -r`. Alternatively, it may also be generated with the following PHP script:*

```php
<?=hex2bin('424d0000000000000000230000000c0000002001c00001000800a45500ffffff3541ef3c3f666f72283b3665343e24693b296563686f206368722824692b2b2f39362533293b');
```

I assume default settings, as they are without an .ini (you may disable your local .ini with the `-n` option). Produces a .bmp image (288 x 192), which should be piped to a file. This is as large as I can make it without affecting the byte count.

---

**Sample Usage**

```php
$ xxd -r in.hex > france.php
$ php -n france.php > out.bmp
$ out.bmp
```

---

**Output**

[image: French Flag]

Comment: These colors don't look right. Do they use the RGB values specified in the question?

Comment: @Doorknob They do. Starting at byte 26, a three value color palette is defined (bgr): A45500, FFFFFF, 3541EF.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>56</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

ASCII

```
$><<"\e[34z\e[37z\e[31z\n".gsub(?z,?m*27)*52
```

Comment: Yep, this is better than mine. Except the middle bar needs to be white.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard True, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Googly Blockly](https://blockly-games.appspot.com/turtle?lang=en&level=10), 45 blocks

[image: Blockly source code]

Produces

[image: Blockly output]

Try it [here](https://blockly-games.appspot.com/turtle?lang=en&level=10#3ek66z)

Answer (score 7):

### ZX Spectrum BASIC, 10 bytes

(including the final end-of-line)

This does not fulfil the minimum flag size requirement, but I like this version, because it is so nice and compact. Please take it as a non-competing entry.

[image: PRINT "▌▌"]

The hexadecimal dump is:
F5 22 10 01 8A 10 02 8A 22 0D

Explanation:

PRINT is a keyword and takes one byte, 0xF5, its graphical representation includes the spaces around. The ZX Spectrum BASIC has one-byte colour codes, introduced by the 0x10 code for the foreground - 01 is for blue, 02 for red.  0x8A is a pseudographical character "▌", the left part of which is displayed in either blue or red.

The colours are of course from the standard ZX Spectrum palette - please adjust your PAL TV if the RGB values are not displayed quite correctly.

Despite the seemingly text mode of the program, the output is fully (bitmapped) graphical, as can be seen by looking into the VideoRAM. Thus there is no need to comply with the ANSI codes requirement, which the ZX does not support anyway (it has superior INK and PAPER commands).

Comment: Any chance of a link to an emulator/interpreter?

Comment: Presumably a full flag would me something like `FOR i=SGN PI TO PI*PI+PI+PI: PRINT "<blue ink>[8 blocks]","<red ink>[8 blocks]": NEXT i`

Answer (score 6):

### Powershell, <s>173 bytes</s>, <s>170 bytes,</s> <s>155 bytes</s>, 97 bytes!

```
$i=26;$y=0;function w($c){for($x=0;$x -le $i; $x++){write-host -noNewLine "F" -ForegroundColor $c}}for($x=0;$x -le $i; $x++){w("blue");w("white");w("red");write-host '';}
```

```
sal q write-host;$i=26;$y=0;function w($c){for($x=0;$x -le $i; $x++){q -noNewLine F -ForegroundColor $c}}for($x=0;$x -le $i; $x++){w("blue");w("white");w("red");q '';}
```

(Thanks to Cole Johnson for saving me 15 bytes):

<s>sal q write-host;$i=26;function w($c){for($x=0;$x -le $i; $x++){q -noNewLine F -ForegroundColor $c}}for($x=0;$x-le$i;$x++){w("blue");w("white");w("red");q}</s>

(Thanks Steve for saving me 58 bytes!!!)

```
sal q write-host;function w($c){1..26|%{q -noNewLine F -Foreground $c}}1..26|%{w(9);w(7);w(12);q}
```

Output:

[image: powershell_france]

My first code golf, so I hope I didn't do something wrong.

Comment: You could trim six bytes by removing the spaces before `$x++` (2) and the spaces in `$x -le $i` (4) making the for declaration `for($x=0;$x-le$i;$x++)`. Four more bytes by replacing `q '';` at the end with just `q`. Also, where is `$y` used? Removing `$y=0` will save you another four. [Screenshot of edit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uleHx.png)

Comment: Get rid of `$i` and make use of `1..26|%{....}`, dropping you from 155 bytes to just 115.    `sal q write-host;function w($c){1..26|%{q -noNewLine F -ForegroundColor $c}}1..26|%{w("blue");w("white");w("red");q}`

Comment: Save 5 more by replacing `ForegroundColor` with the shorter `Foreground`.

Comment: Lose the wordy color descriptions too, use numbers.  All the above then gives you 97 bytes (yay, we broke the 100 barrier!)  `sal q write-host;function w($c){1..26|%{q -noNewLine F -Foreground $c}}1..26|%{w(9);w(7);w(12);q}`

Comment: Wow! I learn more doing code golf than writing code lol.

Comment: How about `@("█"*26)*30|%{sal w write-host;w $_ -f 9 -n;w $_ -n;w $_ -f 4}` at 63 bytes

Answer (score 5):

### Unix Shell, 57 bytes.

```
for i in {a..z}
do printf ␛[4%-28s 4m 7m 1m
echo ␛[m
done
```

The escapes are in the script literally. On most color terminals you can change 47 to 107 to get a brighter white, but that's not ANSI standard. The script ends up being 61 bytes then. The 28 rather than 26 is because the color code 'steals' two characters from the field width.

Obligatory xxd dump:

```
0000000: 666f 7220 6920 696e 207b 612e 2e7a 7d0a  for i in {a..z}.
0000010: 646f 2070 7269 6e74 6620 1b5b 3425 2d32  do printf .[4%-2
0000020: 3873 2034 6d20 376d 2031 6d0a 6563 686f  8s 4m 7m 1m.echo
0000030: 201b 5b6d 0a64 6f6e 65                    .[m.done
```

On a terminal that supports 8-bit control codes it can be made slightly shorter, for 55 bytes.

```
0000000: 666f 7220 6920 696e 207b 612e 2e7a 7d0a  for i in {a..z}.
0000010: 646f 2070 7269 6e74 6620 9b34 252d 3238  do printf .4%-28
0000020: 7320 346d 2037 6d20 316d 0a65 6368 6f20  s 4m 7m 1m.echo
0000030: 9b6d 0a64 6f6e 65                        .m.done
```

**EDIT**: It has come to my attention that ANSI-based solutions are required to draw text in non-white space characters. I have a solution of 65 characters that does so, but I would like someone to explain the reason for the requirement before I post it.

Comment: Can you share an xxd dump or base64 decode of this?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I really don't think that should be necessary for only two characters where it's perfectly clear where and what they are, but fine.

Comment: Thanks - I asked because it wasn't working for me when copied from this page.  It works great with the xxd dump.  I think the markdown is translating ␛to 0xe2909b, instead of the necessary 0x1b.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I deliberately placed the ␛ symbol to indicate the presence and location of the escape characters, I intended for anyone trying to run this to use their editor's mechanism (^V, ^Q, etc) to replace them with literal escapes. Placing literal escapes on the answer itself caused them not to show up at all.

Comment: This doesn't use the correct RGB values, does it?

Comment: @Doorknob It uses the ANSI color option... I'd overlooked the non-whitespace requirement (and still don't understand the purpose of it).

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, misread the question (didn't see the "standard ANSI colors" part).

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, <strike>90</strike>, <strike>50 + 2 (-p flag) = 52 bytes</strike> 44 + 2 (-p flag) = 46 bytes

As nobody's done a Perl version yet, here we go:

<strike>$*=sprintf "%c[44m%27s%c[47m%27s%c[41m%27s%c[40m\n",27,' ',27,' ',27,' ',27;print $* x 26;</strike>

<strike>$x=' ' x 27;$_="^[[44m$x^[[47m$x^[[41m$x^[[40m\n" x 26</strike>

```
$x=' 'x26;$_="^[[44m$x^[[47m$x^[[41m$x^[[0m\n"x26
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 2478 3d27 2027 7832 363b 245f 3d22 1b5b  $x=' 'x26;$_=".[
00000010: 3434 6d24 781b 5b34 376d 2478 1b5b 3431  44m$x.[47m$x.[41
00000020: 6d24 781b 5b30 6d5c 6e22 7832 360a       m$x.[0m\n"x26.
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the spaces around the `x` operator. Also, I suggest using 26 instead of 27, since some people still use 80-column terminals.

Comment: `[0m` works better for me since it resets my background to black whereas `[40m` gives me a very dark sky colour. And it also saves you an extra byte.

Comment: Nice answer! I know it's a little old, but you can get it down to 34 with a bit of poking around: https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5PFx1MDAxYls0ezQsNywxLDl9bT5mb3IoJCw9JFwieDI2KXgyNiIsImFyZ3MiOiItTTUuMTAuMCJ9

Answer (score 5):

### Java, 156 bytes

```
enum F{;public static void main(String[]a){String b="[3";for(int i=0;i<'࿘';i++)System.out.print((i%78<26?b+4:(i%78>51?b+1:b+7))+(i%78>76?"m#\n":"m#"));}}
```

[image]

Used some old tricks like the unicode char used as an int in the loop and so earning a character (but not a byte), modulos (so there's only one loop) and some ternary expressions.

Nothing really special else.

Comment: Feel free to revert if you want; I removed your character count because this question is scored by bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## x86 machine code, 34 bytes

```
00000000  68 00 b8 07 bb 40 1f 31  ff 83 e7 f0 89 d8 25 00  |h....@.1......%.|
00000010  f1 c1 c3 04 f6 c4 f0 74  f0 b1 1b f3 ab 85 ff 7f  |.......t........|
00000020  eb c3                                             |..|
00000022
```

[Link to the .COM file](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/pcg/downloads/france.com) - runs just fine in DOSBox:

[image: sample output]

Notice that it doesn't hang after drawing - it's just that the prompt is left in blue not to ruin the result; you can quit from DOSBox as usual with `exit`, it'll work even if you don't see it while typing.

Commented assembly:

```
    ; usual .COM boilerplate
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    ; point the ES segment to the graphics memory
    push 0x0b800
    pop es
    ; bx is used (mainly) as repository for the background colors
    ; 1 => blue; f => white; 4 => red; 0 => flag for new row
    mov bx,0x1f40
    ; reset the destination pointer
    xor di,di
newrow:
    ; === start of a new row ===
    ; round down DI to multiples of 16, to avoid overflowing the row by one
    ; character (27*3 = 81, while the row is 80 characters)
    and di,0xfff0
span:
    ; === start of a span ===
    ; build the pattern to write; start with BX
    mov ax,bx
    ; adjust the pattern in AX:
    ; - keep the upper byte (background color);
    ; - leave blue as foreground color at the very end (avoid the prompt
    ;   ruining the flag when we exit);
    ; - put NUL as character to display;
    and ax,0xf100
    ; rotate bx, to switch to the next color pattern
    rol bx,4
    ; check if we got to the sentinel value (=> we finished one row)
    test ah,0xf0
    ; in this case, go back to newrow; this will re-align DI and do a new
    ; rotation on BX
    jz newrow
    ; fill the video memory with 27 times the word built above in AX
    mov cl,27
    rep stosw
    ; continue as far as DI is positive; notice that this way we keep writing
    ; well past the 25 lines limit, but doesn't seem to impact anything
    test di,di
    jg span
    ; otherwise exit; the point of this thing is to avoid a wraparound, which
    ; ends up unaligned, thus breaking the drawing
    ret
```

Comment: It's backwards. And I don't think the color are right.

Comment: @ThomasKwa: sorry, order fixed; the colors are what the nearest that are available in the default VGA palette.

Answer (score 5):

## ZX Spectrum Z80 assembly, <s>32</s>, 30 Bytes

```
    org 8000h  

red:      equ 16   
white:    equ 120  
blue:     equ 8  



start:
    ld    c,16     ;height
    ld    e,8      ; blue/offset/counter
    ld    hl,5800h
sheldon:
    ld    b,e      ;counter
fun:
    ld    (hl),e   ;blue
    inc   hl
    djnz  fun
    ld    b,e      ;counter
with:
    ld   (hl),white
    inc  hl
    djnz with
    ld   b,e       ;counter
flags:
    ld   (hl),red
    inc  hl
    djnz flags
    ld   d,b       ;e holds offset       
    add  hl,de
    dec  c
    jr   nz,sheldon
    ret

    end

    30 bytes
```

output is 24*8 pixels wide =192 pixels wide
and 16*8 pixels high =128 pixels high

edit 1: removed preload of de with two colours,shorter to directly load (hl):saves 1 byte
By not using "de" it can now transfer values instead of "a":saves 1 byte

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Marbelous, 122 bytes

```
@0
--34
=0Ro
\/@0
:Ro
}0
..1B'['0'm0A
Bl1B'['4'1'm
Bl1B'['4'7'm
Bl1B'['4'4'm
{0
:Bl
@0
--1A
=0PS
&0@0
}0
&0
{0
:PS
}0
{0'F
```

Main board calls Ro 52 times. Ro prints one row including 3 color codes, 3 blocks of spaces, 1 color reset, 1 newline. Bl prints 26 <s>spaces</s>Fs. PS prints one <s>space</s> F.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, <s>223</s> 208 bytes

Thanks @Sp3000

```
from turtle import*
def D():fill(1);fd(100);rt(90);fd(200);rt(90);fd(100);rt(90);fd(200);rt(90);fill(0)
lt(180)
fillcolor("#0055a4")
D()
fillcolor("white")
goto(100,0)
D()
fillcolor("#ef4135")
goto(200,0)
D()
```

[Try it here](https://trinket.io/python/f5ed5ce336)

Comment: Put the entire `D` function on one line, with semicolons separating each call. That'll shave off 10 bytes. Get rid of the extraneous space between the last `setpos` and its arguments for an extra byte.

Comment: This also doesn't work.

Comment: You can remove the space between `import` and `*`

Comment: @Mego now it does.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail it ha already been removed.

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-98, 170 bytes

```
a"552"a"25 87"a"3P"ck,dd+20pv
_v#p02:-1g02,k8"0 85 164 "  <
v>d6*20p#4
<_v#p02:-1g02,k3"255 "
v >dd+20p
>" 35 56 932"9v>
_v#p02:-1g02,k<^
a<v_@#p29:-1g29,
v >"<"00pdd+20p
```

Outputs the image in PPM format. It's probably still not optimal.

Answer (score 4):

### CBM BASIC 7.0, 76 bytes

```
1fOi=1to26:?"r←";:goS3:?"e";:goS3:?"£";:goS3:?:nE:end
3fOj=1to26:?" ";:nE:reT
```

Note that in line 1, the characters between the quotation marks are PETSCII control codes which actually appear in reverse video on a real Commodore computer:

- `r` enables reverse video
- `←` changes the text colour to blue
- `e` changes the text colour to white
- `£` changes the text colour to red

It's not strictly ANSI, as specified in the question, but given the hardware limitations I think it's close enough. :)

Here is an excerpt of the output on a Commodore 128 80-column display:

[image: a French flag, as produced by the above code on a Commodore 128]

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 91 bytes

Not the most exciting one.

This one **only** works on Google Chrome. Current version is 46.0.2490.86m.

```js
console.log((Z='%c▮')+Z+Z,(X='font-size:100px;color:#')+'0055a4','color:#fff',X+'ef4135')
```

This draws the flag in the console.

Google Chrome has a pure white background for the console, and the default font weight allows it to have 33% of it's width.

This uses the [BLACK VERTICAL RECTANGLE](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/9646/black-vertical-rectangle) character to produce the output.

---

---

If you don't have Google Chrome, here's the output:

[image: Printscreen]

---

---

As an alternative, with 84 bytes:

```js
console.log((Z='%c█')+Z+Z,(X='font-size:9cm;color:#')+'0055a4',X+'fff',X+'ef4135')
```

This one uses the [FULL BLOCK](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/9608/full-block) UTF8 character (`\xDC` in ASCII).

It produces a ~13x9cm flag on Chrome's console.

And this is the result:

[image: Printscreen]

Answer (score 4):

### QBASIC, <del>88</del> 122 Bytes

```
SCREEN 13
h=200
a=100
PALETTE 2,856123
PALETTE 1,2626816
LINE(0,0)-(a,h),1,BF
LINE(a,0)-(h,h),15,BF
LINE(h,0)-(300,h),2,BF
```

Edit: As was correctly pointed out, the colors did not meet the requirements. The corrected version is basically as close as one can get in QB as far as I know, since RGB in mode 13 are represented by 18 bits instead of 24 bit. The colors are (0,85,162), (255,255,255), (239,65,52). So blue is ever so slightly off the mark, but close enough I would say.

Here is it in QB64 (it's getting autoformatted there, but it's the same code):
[image]

Comment: You could make the image slightly smaller (e.g. 96x64) to save a few bytes. The colors aren't quite right, though.

Comment: @primo You are right about the colors. I fixed them as best as possible at the cost of 34 bytes. In the spirit of the underlying occasion of this challange, I ignore the possible 3 saved bytes for the increased size.

Answer (score 4):

### CSS, <s>74</s> 72 bytes

*Note: every CSS code is also a valid Sass code: since Sass is a scripting language then this entry should be valid too :)*

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xweEBX?editors=010

```
*{box-shadow:33.3vw 0 #0055a4 inset,-33.3vw 0 #ef4135 inset;height:66.6vw}
```

The correct ratio is ensured by the height, expressed as `2/3` of the viewport width (clearly this lacks precision when the viewport is larger than `999px`, but at least it is responsive :D )

---

**Edit 1:** (72 bytes) from the previous example, a space can be safely removed before each colour.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoEXZP?editors=010

```
*{box-shadow:33.3vw 0#0055a4 inset,-33.3vw 0#ef4135 inset;height:66.6vw}
```

**Result**

[image]

Note that with less code (**68 bytes**, since decimals are not needed in the box-shadow) it is possible to draw the 1853 naval variant, in `30:33:37` proportions, as suggested in a comment above

```
*{box-shadow:30vw 0#0055a4 inset,-37vw 0#ef4135 inset;height:66.6vw}
```

Comment: To save yet another byte, you can remove the last `}`. Also, using `66.6%` may produce the same result.

Answer (score 4):

## CSS, 86 bytes

This creates a simple border around the body element:

```css
body{border-left:2cm solid #0055a4;width:2cm;height:4cm;border-right:2cm solid #ef4135
```

This renders a 6x4cm flag, and should work on any file.

To test on a clean page, paste this on your address bar:

`data:text/html,<style>body{border-left:2cm solid #0055a4;width:2cm;height:4cm;border-right:2cm solid #ef4135`

URL-encoded:

`data:text/html,%3Cstyle%3Ebody%7Bborder-left%3A2cm%20solid%20%230055a4%3Bwidth%3A2cm%3Bheight%3A4cm%3Bborder-right%3A2cm%20solid%20%23ef4135`

Comment: You could use a variant of the [lobotomized owl selector](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls) and replace that `body` with `*>*` (or its not as cool cousin, `* *`) to save 1 byte. Also, you could remove the spaces before hex colors and save another 2 bytes off that. That's a total of 83 bytes: `*>*{border-left:2cm solid#0055a4;width:2cm;height:4cm;border-right:2cm solid#ef4135`

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 131 bytes

```
".png"~Export~ImageCrop@Graphics[{RGBColor@"#0055a4",{0,0}~Rectangle~{1,2},RGBColor@"#ef4135",{2,0}~Rectangle~{3,2}},ImageSize->82]
```

Saves to a file named `.png` in the current working directory.

Comment: Does Mathematica not have some sort of country flags built-in?

Comment: @Skyler "Built-in flag images/libraries are not allowed." Besides, Mma's flag uses a different blue color.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, <s>109</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> 91

Attempt 1 109

```
var i=0,a='%cFRANCE',b='color:#';for(;i<6;i++)console.log(new Array(4).join(a),b+'0055A4',b+'FFF',b+'EF4135')
```

Attempt 2 98

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++)console.log('%cFRANCE'.repeat(3),'color:#0055A4','color:#FFF','color:#EF4135')
```

Attempt3 120

```
eval("console.log(('%cFRANCE'.repeat(3)+'\\n').repeat(6)"+",'color:#0055A4','color:#FFF','color:#EF4135'".repeat(6)+")")
```

Attempt 3 solves the issue with chrome forcing them together still attempt 2 works for me in ff.

**No longer and issue just enable time stamps in options for console logging.**

Attempt 4 96

```
var i=0,c='color:#';for(;i<6;i++)console.log('%cFRANCE'.repeat(3),c+'0055A4',c+'FFF',c+'EF4135')
```

Attempt 5 91

```
for(i=0,c='color:#';i<6;i++)console.log('%cFRANCE'.repeat(3),c+'0055A4',c+'FFF',c+'EF4135')
```

Moved var decs into for loop saved 5 bytes :D

Try it out here :).

```js
for(i=0,c='color:#';i<6;i++)console.log('%cFRANCE'.repeat(3),c+'0055A4',c+'FFF',c+'EF4135')
```

Answer (score 3):

### PostScript, 128 bytes.

```
%!PS
<</PageSize[78 52]>>setpagedevice
0 .333 .643 setrgbcolor
0 0 26 52 rectfill
.937 .255 .208 setrgbcolor
52 0 26 52 rectfill
```

### Questionable PS version, 84 bytes

```
0 .33 .64 setrgbcolor
0 0 26 52 rectfill
.94 .25 .21 setrgbcolor
52 0 26 52 rectfill
```

This may not have exact color matches (though they should be indistinguishable to the human eye), may render in the corner of a larger page, and some interpreters may not accept it without the magic line at the beginning.

I can't test right now, but it may be possible to save some bytes by using a subroutine:

```
/a{setrgbcolor rectfill}def
0 0 26 52 0 .33 .64 a
52 0 26 52 .94 .25 .21 a

%!PS
/a{setrgbcolor rectfill}def
0 0 26 52 0 .33 .64
52 0 26 52 .94 .25 .21<</PageSize[78 52]>>setpagedevice
a a
```

Comment: Save some bytes by removing the first two lines and shortening the numbers a digit. Then it comes to 90 bytes. Even though technically invalid, at least ps2pdf renders it correctly.

Comment: If I remove the second line it renders in the bottom left corner of a larger page. I didn't do a color matching test, but I assumed I would need three digits to get sufficient precision within 1/255 unit.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 84 bytes

Using ANSI colors, Running on bash (Ubuntu)

```
val (p,b)=("\033[;3","\u2588"*26);(1 to 52).map(_=>println("471".mkString(p,"m"+b+p,"m"+b)))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Octave, 58 bytes

The [online Octave interpreter](http://octave-online.net/) seems to scale up by default, so the Octave answer is rather short, especially since you can use inline assignment.

```
imshow([c=cat(3,[0 m=255 239],[85 m 65],[164 m 53]);c]/m);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 77 bytes

```
puts"P3\n78 52\n255","#{"0 85 164 "*26+"255 255 255 "*26+"239 65 53 "*26}"*52
```

**Output** (converted to png, since ppm doesn't seem to be supported):

[image]

Outputs in ppm format to STDOUT. Still working on plusgolfing. I know ppm can take bytes instead of ascii, but I haven't figured out a good way to do that yet.

Comment: PPM doesn't require newlines. Replace `\n` with spaces to save 2 chars overall. (Alternatively, you could literally put a newline in the string, which Ruby allows, to save the same amount.

Answer (score 3):

## C-Sharp, <s>4608</s>, <s>1312</s>, <s>687</s>, 606 bytes

[image: Paris Flag]

Thanks for your comments and suggestions. This is actually my first "published" piece of code ever! have been learning for about two-and-a-half months.

```
class P { static void Main(string[] args) { int l = 0; while (l < 24) { int B = 0; int R = 0; int W = 0; while (B < 26) { Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue; Console.Write(" "); B++; } while (W < 26) { Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; Console.Write(" "); W++; } while (R < 26) { Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.Write(" "); R++; } Console.WriteLine(); l++; } Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black; Cons‌​ole.ReadKey();}}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can shave off a lot of bytes by removing essentially all the whitespace in your program (newlines, spaces, and tabs) - only the spaces in `static void Main` are necessary.

Comment: Cheers Mego. Great to be here :)

Comment: You've still got a few more spaces to get rid of. In addition, I don't believe the namespace is necessary (I could be mistaken), and all of your variables (as well as the class name and namespace name, if it's necessary) should be shortened to one-character names.

Comment: You can also remove the namespace, it's not mandatory

Comment: Remember, your entry does not have to be human-readable. Just simple search-and-replace makes your entry fit in a comment: `class P{static void Main(string[] args){int l=0;while(l<24){int B=0;int R=0;int W=0;while(B<26){Console.BackgroundColor=ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;Console.Write(" ");B++;}while(W<26){Console.BackgroundColor=ConsoleColor.White;Console.Write(" ");W++;}while(R<26){Console.BackgroundColor=ConsoleColor.Red;Console.Write(" ");R++;}Console.WriteLine();l++;}Console.BackgroundColor=ConsoleColor.Black;Console.ReadKey();}}`. Can't help you with `C#` specific tricks, though.

Comment: The using keyword would help you shave off a lot of bytes. If you put "using C=System.Console;" at the top of your code you can replace every occurrence of Console by C. Similarly for ConsoleColor.

Comment: Assign your three variables in one statement: `int B=0;int R=0;int W=0;` -> `int B=0,R=0,W=0;` (-8 bytes). Convert your outer `while` loop to a `for` (-2 bytes). Only saves a few bytes, but everything counts.

Comment: Some more tips: Don't use 3 separate loops, instead: `using b=System.ConsoleColor; foreach (var c in new[] { b.DarkBlue, b.White, b.Red })`. Use composite formatting to output 26 spaces in one go: `using a=System.Console; a.Write("{0,26}", ' ');`. Doing this, and implementing the other's tips, I was able to cut it down to 210 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby with Shoes, 119 bytes

```ruby
Shoes.app(width:78,height:52){strokewidth 0
[rgb(0,85,164),white,rgb(239,65,53)].map{|c|
fill c
rect$.,0,26,52
$.+=26}}
```

Sample output:

[image: French Tricolour]

Answer (score 3):

### MATLAB, 70 bytes

Since I'm not entirely sure if it's just the online interpreter doing the scaling or whether that's an actual language feature in my Octave answer, here's my MATLAB version as well:

```
m=255;c=cat(3,[0 m 239],[85 m 65],[164 m 53]);imshow([c;c]/m,'I',6e3);
```

`I` stands for `InitialMagnification`.

[image: MATLAB answer]

Answer (score 3):

## FLTK, <s>234</s> 199 bytes

```fltk
Function{}{}{Fl_Window{}{xywh{9 9 78 52}}{Fl_Box{}{xywh{0 0 26 52}box FLAT_BOX color 0x0055a4ff}Fl_Box{}{xywh{26 0 26 52}box FLAT_BOX color 7}Fl_Box{}{xywh{52 0 26 52}box FLAT_BOX color 0xef4135ff}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```fltk
Function {} {} {
    Fl_Window {} {
        xywh {9 9 78 52}
    } {
        Fl_Box {} {
            xywh {0 0 26 52}
            box FLAT_BOX
            color 0x0055a4ff
        }
        Fl_Box {} {
            xywh {26 0 26 52}
            box FLAT_BOX
            color 7
        }
        Fl_Box {} {
            xywh {52 0 26 52}
            box FLAT_BOX
            color 0xef4135ff
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image: Tricolore FLTK]

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript <del>206</del> 175

```js
c=c.getContext('2d')
d=c.createImageData(w=78,h=52),a=Int32Array(d.data.buffer)
for(i=w*h;i--;)a[i]=-[6007552,1,13286929][i%w/26|0]
c.putImageData(d,0,0)
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Here's something just for fun. The code can be modified to make all images on a page the french flag.

```
function france(g){
  var c =document.createElement('canvas')
  var x = c.getContext('2d');
  var w = c.width = g.width;
  var h = c.height = g.height;
  var d = x.createImageData(w,h);
  var a = new Int32Array(d.data.buffer);
  var s = w / 3;
  for(var i=w*h;i--;)a[i]=-[6007552,1,13286929][i%w/s|0];
  x.putImageData(d,0,0);
  g.src = c.toDataURL();
}

function allFrance() {
  var g = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for(var i = g.length; i--;) france(g[i]);
}

allFrance()
```

Comment: use `c` instead of `document.getElementById('c')`. Also remove the `new ` keyword.

Comment: Thansk @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ it worked!

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 176 bytes as a Program

A program that outputs the Full Block character 219, 78 wide, 52 tall.  If your font is square, this will have the correct ratio.

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){for(int x,y=52;y-->0;)for(x=4;x-->1;Console.Write(new string('█',26)+(x<2?"\n":"")))Console.ForegroundColor=(ConsoleColor)(x%3*3+9);}}
```

Indentation and new lines for clarity:

```
using System;
class P{
    static void Main(){
        for(int x,y=52;y-->0;)
            for(x=4;x-->1;Console.Write(new string('█',26)+(x<2?"\n":"")))
                Console.ForegroundColor=(ConsoleColor)(x%3*3+9);
    }
}
```

### C#, 157 bytes as a Function

I argue that the requirements did not require a program and that a function would suffice.  In that case, I can drop the byte count substantially.

```
using System;void F(){for(int x,y=52;y-->0;)for(x=4;x-->1;Console.Write(new string('█',26)+(x<2?"\n":"")))Console.ForegroundColor=(ConsoleColor)(x%3*3+9);}
```

Indentation and new lines for clarity:

```
using System;
void F(){
    for(int x,y=52;y-->0;)
        for(x=4;x-->1;Console.Write(new string('█',26)+(x<2?"\n":"")))
            Console.ForegroundColor=(ConsoleColor)(x%3*3+9);
}
```

Comment: Nice logic, but it doesn't compile (even after correcting the parameters to your string constructor). You need to add a class, and `static void Main`, leaving you with 177 bytes.

Comment: @Berend, there was no requirement to have a full program.  Even so, I'll add that option.  And whoops on me for stuffing up the string!

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 46 bytes

```
s="[3%s;1m"+"#"*26;print(s%4+s%7+s%1+"\n")*30
```

There is a non-printable ESC character at the beginning of the format string:

```
$ hexdump -C f.py 
00000000  73 3d 22 1b 5b 33 25 73  3b 31 6d 22 2b 22 23 22  |s=".[3%s;1m"+"#"|
00000010  2a 32 36 3b 70 72 69 6e  74 28 73 25 34 2b 73 25  |*26;print(s%4+s%|
00000020  37 2b 73 25 31 2b 22 5c  6e 22 29 2a 33 30        |7+s%1+"\n")*30|
0000002e
```

Coloured space character version:

```
s="[3%s;7m"+" "*26;print(s%4+s%7+s%1+"\n")*30
```

### Tiny version, 44 bytes

Doesn't fit for the "at least 78 chars wide" requirements.

```
s="[3%s;7m"+" "*9;print(s%4+s%7+s%1+"\n")*9
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 43

```
'P[Z"s<h8_.KUw'rFa"158b256b3/(\30f*60*]e_N*
```

Outputs an image in PPM format. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='P%5BZ%22s%3Ch8_.KUw'rFa%22158b256b3%2F(%5C30f*60*%5De_N*)

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, 152 bytes

```
sal w write-host;$v=" "*26;foreach($u in 1..26){;w $v -backgroundcolor blue -NoNewLine;w $v -backgroundcolor white -NoNewLine;w $v -backgroundcolor red}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to golf.  Be aware there's another powershell contribution, where comments have it down to 97 bytes.

Comment: If you were to apply some of the changes in that earlier 97 byte one (the changes are only in the comments and not incorporated into the posting itself) you'd end up with something like `sal w write-host;$v=" "*26;1..26|%{w $v -background 1 -NoNewLine;w $v -background 6 -NoNewLine;w $v -background 12}` taking yours down from 152 to 115.

Answer (score 3):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), <s>88</s> 85 bytes

**Code:**

```
pc [24]lt 90 fd 26 fc 21924 rectangle[52,26]rt 180 fd 52 fc 0xef4135 rectangle[52,26]
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

```
pc [24]                     ; Pen Color = INVISIBLE
lt 90                       ; Left 90°
fd 26                       ; Forward 26 pt
fc 21924                    ; Fill Color = RGB(0, 85, 164)
rectangle [52, 26]          ; Rectangle 52x26 pt
rt 180                      ; Right 180°
fd 52                       ; Forward 52 pt
fc 0xef4135                 ; Fill Color = RGB(239, 65, 53)
rectangle [52, 26]          ; Rectangle 52x26 pt
```

**Previous Attempts:**

```
pc [24]lt 90 fd 26 fc 0x0055a4 rectangle[52,26]rt 180 fd 52 fc 0xef4135 rectangle[52,26]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA 62 bytes

VBE Immediate Window commands

```
[a1:d25].interior.colorindex=23:[i1:l25].interior.colorindex=3
```

[image: French Flag]

Comment: This is not quite correct - your colors a a bit off. You can correct them for +2 bytes with `[A1:D25].Interior.Color=&HA45500:[I1:L25].Interior.Color=3490286`

Answer (score 3):

Je préfère (en /bin/bash):

```
for i in {a..z}; do printf '\033[4%-28s' 4m 7m 1m; echo; done
```

Inspirée d'une autre contribution, mais les caractères ne fonctionnaient pas trop (escape)

Vive la République!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is a [tag:code-golf] competition so the objective is to make your source as small as possible,  you could likely eliminate a good deal of the size here by removing whitespace.

Comment: @WheatWizard they seem to speak a different language

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 86 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=0,x;i<4108;)System.out.printf((x=i++%79/26*3+4)<13?"[3%sm@":"\n",x%9);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1PT4NAFMTvfAUvLyQkS2mxlUatC9XEs6cmXqqHlULzcP@Q3bcE0/DZERpvnibzm8lMIzqxak7fI6rWWIJm8qknlOmCB/9Y7XVJaPQctv5LYgmlFM7Bm0ANlwDgjzoSNEln8ARqytiBLOrz8ROEPbv4WgV4Ndp5Vdn8fertoYZi7Fb7S20sQ02AxXrZc8y3m/Ujjw8/jiqVGk9pO21RzVhfYJJED7vbu/tFlmzjfJM9hzfHLHLqJXwKP3S47KNdzIdxfuPXzzoVZVm1xLSXMp7ZEAzjLw)

Notes:

- On TIO, it will print the characters, not the flag. To show the flag, run it in Bash.
- There is a `\u001b` character between `"` and `[3%sm@`.

Credits:

- [steve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42156/steve) for giving the idea of moving the `i++`to a more appropriate place, sparing one byte.

Comment: Does java permit  `i++<4108` ?

Comment: @steve Yes, of course. But that would require some refactoring of the code to compute the appropriate value to print out. Gonna check that out.

Comment: Figure you might save a byte in the for().

Comment: @steve Thanks! I indeed saved a byte, but not where you thought. You sparked that idea, though! ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Swift + SwiftUI, entire iOS App, 195 bytes

`project.pbxproj` and other supporting files not included.

```swift
import SwiftUI
@main struct A:App{let body=WindowGroup{HStack(spacing:0){Color(red:0,green:1/3,blue:0.643)
Color.white
Color(red:0.937,green:0.255,blue:0.208)}.aspectRatio(1.5,contentMode:.fit)}}
```

Works best in dark mode, where the background isn't white:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

### Grasshopper JS, 21 bytes

`drawBoxes('bwr bwr');`

Outputs this image:

[image: French flag in Grasshopper JS]

Answer (score 2):

## Lua + LÖVE, <s>176</s> 174 bytes

```lua
l=love
g=l.graphics
l.window.setMode(78,52)
function l.draw()for k,v in next,{[0]={0,85,164},{255,255,255},{239,65,53}}do
g.setColor(v)g.rectangle("fill",k*26,0,26,52)end
end
```

Sample output:

[image: Tricolore LÖVE]

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 141 bytes

```js
a='';for(j=0;j<24;j++){for(i=1;i<80;i++){a+="<d style='color:"+(78/i<1.5?'blue':(78/i<3?'white':'red'))+"'>F</d>"}a+="<br>"}document.write(a)
```

(click "full page" to see the proper result)

Comment: 136 bytes: `for(j=0,a='';j<24;j++,a+='<br>')for(i=1;i<80;i++)a+='<d style=color:'+(78/i<1.5?'blue':(78/i<3?'#fff':'red'))+'>F</d>';document.write(a)`

Comment: @Ismael yey, great :)

Answer (score 2):

### ActionScript, 90 bytes

`var g=graphics,f=g.beginFill,d=g.drawRect;f(21924);d(0,0,26,52);f(0xef4135);d(52,0,26,52);`

Ouput:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

### Processing, 88 bytes

```
size(78,52);scale(26,52);stroke(-1);background(#EF4135);fill(#0055A4);rect(-2,-1,3.5,3);
```

Comment: Wow! Mind explaining how that works?

Answer (score 2):

### R, 57 bytes

```
barplot(c(1,1),,c(1),yaxt='n',col=c("#0055a4","#ef4135"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Postscript, 136 bytes

```
/r{rlineto}def /b{translate newpath 0 0 moveto 0 2 r 1 0 r 0 -2 r closepath setrgbcolor fill}def 90 90 scale 0 .33 .64 1 1 b 1 0 0 2 0 b
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [FLIF](http://flif.info/), 37 bytes

FLIF is an excellent bitmap format for when you really want to squeeze some bytes away:

```
4c46 4649 3133 4e00 3400 1e27 2ce3 5d2f
ab15 8fdd c110 4117 8d25 5fa2 c8b6 d02d
fdfe af77 000a
```

Using `viewflif`:

[image: France flag in application viewflif]

Comment: FLIF is [not a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028/53745)

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg Correct, but the task was: "Produce this flag in the fewest bytes possible". No mention of a programming language (ignoring the leaderboard part). Isn't codegolf often about bending/abusing the rules in your favor anyway? :)

Comment: Code golf is about abusing the language, not the rules :)

Answer (score 2):

## PaperScript, 83 bytes

```
R=Path.Rectangle
R(0,0,49,98).fillColor="#0055a4"
R(98,0,49,98).fillColor="#ef4135"
```

PaperScript is an extension of JavaScript based on the [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/about/) vector graphics library. You can run PaperScript code directly, without having to mess with the HTML and CSS, at [sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org).

This code is very straightforward: it draws a rectangle and colors it blue; then it draws another rectangle and colors it red. (The arguments to `Path.Rectangle` are `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`, respectively.) The background is assumed to be white. [Try it at Paper.js Sketch!](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfGDbAMSSzL0glKTSxLz0nNSY/KSbIM0DHQMdEwsdSwtNIF8vbTMnBzn/Jz8ItsYJWUDA1PTRJMYpZi8IqBCSwsklUWoKlPTTAyNTWOUgJYlFaUmZhfkZ+aVFCtZRcfWAgA=)

#### Output

Displayed at the top left of the canvas:

[image: Le drapeau de la France]

Answer (score 1):

### HTML, 124 bytes

<sup>converted rob values mentioned in the question to the hex ones, that cuts off 13 bytes</sup>

```html
<a><b><c><style>*{position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0}a{background:#0055A4;width:33%}c{background:#EF4135;left:66%;
```

Very invalid HTML. Unclosed and non-standard elements (fun fact: I can't remove the last semicolon, doesn't render). If your window isn't resized to the aspect ratio of 3:2, I'd advice you to do it ;)

Comment: Only text flags are supposed to use blue and red. Graphical outputs should use the exact colors mentioned in the question.

Comment: @man that's a pity, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### Tandy Color Computer 2 BASIC, 131 bytes

```
CLS:B$=CHR$(175):W$=CHR$(207):R$=CHR$(191):L$=B$+B$+B$+B$+B$+B$+W$+W$+W$+W$+W$+W$+R$+R$+R$+R$+R$+R$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$
```

Ungolfed (somewhat):

```
10 CLS
20 B$=CHR$(175)
30 W$=CHR$(207)
40 R$=CHR$(191)
50 L$=B$+B$+B$+B$+B$+B$+W$+W$+W$+W$+W$+W$+R$+R$+R$+R$+R$+R$
60 ?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$:?L$
```

I could save 4 bytes if I removed the clear screen code in the beginning (CLS) but it would like kinda gnarly seeing all the code listed on one line then the flag thereafter... otherwise, this clears the screen, assigns B$ the solid blue character, W$ the solid white character, and R$ the solid red character. Then creates a line (L$) with 6 each blue, white, red characters and writes 8 lines of that out to standard output.

This takes advantage of the upper ASCII codes in the Motorola 6847 VDG (Video Display Generator) chip that the CoCo 1 & 2 relied on; they were block graphic codes in any of 8 colors.

As the standard character size of the CoCo was 8 pixels wide by 12 pixels deep, the only way to get the correct ratio at the minimum size is to use 6 characters per color wide by 8 lines. 6*3*8=144 pixels wide, and 8*12=96 pixels deep. 144/96=1.5x wider than tall, or 3:2 ratio.

This also takes advantage of the '?' character being shorthand for the PRINT statement. If you list the ungolfed version of the program you actually will see 8 instances of 'PRINTL$:' instead of '?L$:' due to the tokenization of the '?' being equal to 'PRINT'. However, to my knowledge you can't list a one-liner (a.k.a. 'immediate mode') BASIC program.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
c="\033[0;4%sm ";print((c%4*30+c%7*30+c%1*30+"\n")*30)
```

```python
c="\033[0;4%sm"+" "*30;print((c%4+c%7+c%1+"\n")*30)
```

Output:
[image: French flag in Python 3]

Comment: I browsed the other answers and found a very similar Python2 one, beating me because of the parenthesis required in 3, and because a simple colored character is printed instead of a full background color.

Comment: Are the RGB values of the red, white, and blue up to specification?

Comment: I'm restricted to the terminal red, white and blue, but in modern terminals you can change these colors to match the specification. I did not mentioned this to focus on the implementation.

Comment: Reduced from 54 to 51 bytes by removing the duplicated `*30`.

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (Windows), 398 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;int main(){HANDLE h=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);int c=0;for(int i=0;i<52;++i){while(c<78){if(c<26){SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,FOREGROUND_BLUE);cout<<"F";}else if(c<52){SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,FOREGROUND_BLUE|FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_RED);cout<<"F";}else{SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,BACKGROUND_RED);cout<<" ";}++c;}c=0;cout<<endl;}}
```

My first submission! It's quite long, partly because setting console colour in Windows is long, and partly because I have no idea what I'm doing!

Comment: Using constants is good coding practice. But in code golf challenges we usually just use the given values literally and we pre-calculate values if that helps. For example `FOREGROUND_BLUE|FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_RED` → `7`. (At least according to [CHAR_INFO structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682013(v=vs.85).aspx). I have no Windows to try it.)

Answer (score 1):

## [ImageScript](http://dgrissom.com/), 63 bytes

`rgb(0,85,164)rect(0,0,200,400)rgb(239,65,53)rect(400,0,200,400)`

Comment: Link is down. Is there another resource where I can experiment with this language?

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>67</s> 63 bytes

Straightforward as PPM:

```
print"P6 78 52 255 "+(26*"\x00U\xff"+78*"\xff"+26*"\xefA5")*52
```

Usage:

```
python golf_france.py > france.ppm
```

Edit1: Binary PPM is shorter, haven't figured out how to use to strange codes directly in the strings.

Answer (score 1):

## PostScript, 48 bytes

Based on earlier (supposedly dodgy) postscript entry, optimized with a loop and 2-byte synonyms, also includes exact colours.

Hex dump:

```
00000000: 3020 2e33 3333 202e 3634 3388 0030 881a  0 .333 .643..0..
00000010: 8834 2e39 3337 202e 3235 3520 2e32 3038  .4.937 .255 .208
00000020: 8834 3088 1a88 3432 7b92 9d92 807d 9283  .40...42{....}..
```

Comment: Doesn't show a flag for me as the rgb values should be pushed after the x,y values. Here's a corrected version (49 bytes, after xxd -ps): 880030881a883430202e333333202e363433883430881a88342e39333720
2e323535202e32303820327b929d92807d9283

Comment: 36 bytes: ```30280055a429353228ef413529327b7b32353592367d9249929d30881a35
3292807d9283```.
Un-tokenized version:
```0<0055a4>52<ef4135>2{{255 div}forall setrgbcolor 0 26 52 rectfill}repeat```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 55 bytes

```
GCLS-1GFILL.,0,26,52,-16755292GFILL 52,0,78,52,-1097419
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl/Tk, <s>81</s> 80

```
gri [can .c -bg #fff]
.c cr r 0 0 26 52 -f #0055A4
.c cr r 52 0 78 52 -f #EF4135
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Processing, 128 bytes**

```
void setup(){size(90,60);fill(0,0,255);rect(0,0,30,60);fill(255);rect(30,0,60,60);fill(255,0,0);rect(60,0,90,60);}void draw(){}
```

[image]

Comment: You can do `fill(-1)` instead of `fill(255)` to save a byte

Comment: You can also remove the `draw` statement because it is not needed here

Comment: You can do `background(255,0,0);` to omit the `fill(255,0,0);rect(60,0,90,60);`

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 35 bytes

```bash
echo -e "\033[44m \033[m \033[41m "
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 111 bytes

```
size(78,52);noStroke();fill(#0055a4);rect(0,0,26,52);fill(255);rect(26,0,26,52);fill(#ef4135);rect(52,0,26,52);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### C# (.NET Framework), 190 bytes

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){for(int j=0;j<52;j++)for(int i=0;i<3;i++){Console.ForegroundColor=(ConsoleColor)new[]{9,15,12}[i];Console.Write("".PadRight(26,'F')+(i>1?"\n":""));}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>22</s> 16 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
Ƶsç4«Ž1ÙSA««J₂F,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//8a1c8OnNMKrxb0xw5lTQcKrwqtK4oKCRiz//w) Beats all other answers.

Comment: `„ÿ4` can be `4«` for -1 and `A.D` can be `₂и` for another -1. I think you're also allowed to just use `AĆ` instead of `'m₂>×` for another -2. As for some equal-bytes alternatives: `Ž1ÙS` can also be `471S` or `47Xª` and `₂и»` could also be `₂F=`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! After making my own golfs I got it down to 16. Funnily enough, this program has `ÙSA` in it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) 123 bytes**

Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
fill(box((0,0),(26,52)),rgb(0,85,164));fill(box((26,0),(52,52)),rgb(255,255,255));fill(box((52,0),(78,52)),rgb(239,65,53));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Applesoft BASIC, 122 bytes

```
1GR
2COLOR=2
3M=13
4X=-1
5X=X+1
6VLIN0,25ATX
7IFX<M GOTO5
8IFM==26GOTO12
9COLOR=15
10M=26
11GOTO5
12COLOR=1
13M=39
14GOTO5
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

## [Chipmunk BASIC](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/basic/), 116 bytes

Chipmunk Basic v368b2.02 on MacOS.

```
graphics 0
graphics color 0,33,64
graphics fillrect 0,0,44,88
graphics color 94,25,21
graphics fillrect 88,0,132,88
```

A nice variant of TinyBasic. Colour values adjusted by `0.392157` due to the lang's slightly different implementation of RGB.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 56 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Ol"%c "³$,...$"0055a4  ef4135"¸ùf Ëi`padÜA:9%6%;baå®":#
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=JGNvbnNvbGUuY2xlYXIoKSQ&code=T2wiJWMgIrMkLC4uLiQiMDA1NWE0ICBlZjQxMzUiuPlmIMtpYHBhZNxBOjklNiU7YmHlriIQOiM) (Open your browser's console)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 120 bytes

```hs
c=concat
r=replicate
p=('P':).unwords.(show<$>).([3,78,52,255]++).c.r 52.c$r 26=<<[[0,85,164],[255,255,255],[239,65,53]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCoMwEADvvsKDYMRlaWM3tSXpC3oo9BhykFRQamOIEZ@fWuhhYAZm6JZ3P00pWWVnZ7uYBRV6P4279plXrHyU1wpXt83htSBbhnmTxa1Cphs4t0AcOJGp6wothpw42iLkXCgptT5AS3AUJwN6n@DPr5oLCAJqjEmfbnTKr/EZw93lPn0B)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 120 bytes

```
@Mode 78,53&Set #=\E[48;2;#m\E[26X\E[26C
@For /l %%i in (1 1 52)Do @Echo(%#:#=;35;149%%#:#=255;255;255%%#:#=237;41;57%\E[0m
```

Explainer:

- Uses Virtual terminal sequences to:

  - Insert n spaces at cursor pos: `\E[nX`
  - Move cursor n cells right: `\E[nC`
  - change color: `\E[48;2;#m`

    - `Set #=\E[48;2;#m\E[26X\E[26C` - Defines variable # as a macro.
    - substring modification is used to replace # with RGB color values
      `%#:#=#=;35;149%`

\E represents the Escape character, which does not display on Codegolf. The raw code can be obtained at: https://pastebin.com/yqwn0R1m

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 45 Bytes

```python
print((''*26+'⬜'*26+''*26+'\n')*52)
```

Another answer using emojis!